# Capturar quantidade de Itens no Carrinho WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de capturar a quantidade de itens no carrinho do Woocommerce no Wordpress, se há algum shortcode, etc.

Comment: Eu posso te ajudar, mas preciso tirar umas dúvidas: Você quer a quantidade numérica de cada cliente, no ato de suas requisições ou quer o total geral?

Comment: No caso, total geral, pelo seguinte, na minha ideia, o icone do carrinho de compras ficará no lado superior direito do website e indicando o numero de itens no carrinho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar no seu template o total utilize isto:

```
<?php 

    global $woocommerce;
    $numero = sprintf(_n('%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'));

    echo $numero;

?>
```